# Group By pandas dataframe and keep earliest date from one column and the latest date from another column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following data:

```
id   start_date   end_date
1    2023-01-01   2023-02-02
1    2023-02-05   2023-02-15
1    2023-02-16   2023-03-14
```

How can I group by id and keep the earliest date from `start_date` and the latest from `end_date` . E.g.

```
id   start_date   end_date
1    2023-01-01   2023-03-14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max and min work fine for dates. Use:

```
df2 = df.groupby('id').agg({'start_date': min, 'end_date': max}).reset_index()
```

to give:

```
   id  start_date    end_date
0   1  2023-01-01  2023-03-14
```

Answer (score 1):

group by id, the selecting max, min for the columns:

```
df.groupby("id").agg({"start_date": min, "end_date":max}).reset_index(drop=False)
```